# MySQL Join Query on age range

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table that I am working with that contain what I need for my query.  I need to return age groups for a given sale date range and display the profits for each.  Here is the query that I am which is returning an error:

> #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

```
SELECT DealInfo.DeliveryDate, Coalesce(SUM(Commissions.GrossProfit),0) as GP, CASE 
WHEN age < 16 THEN 'Under 16'
WHEN age BETWEEN 16 and 20 THEN '16 - 20' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 21 and 25 THEN '21 - 25' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 26 and 30 THEN '26 - 30' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 31 and 35 THEN '31 - 35' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 36 and 40 THEN '36 - 40' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 41 and 45 THEN '41 - 45' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 46 and 50 THEN '46 - 50' 
WHEN age BETWEEN 51 and 55 THEN '51 - 55' 
WHEN age > 55 THEN 'Over 55' 
WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'NULL' END as age_range, 
COUNT(*) AS RC FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age
FROM customers WHERE Customers.dob<>'0000-00-00' and Customers.server_id = '0000001412') as derived
GROUP BY age_range
ORDER BY age_range ASC
from DealInfo 
LEFT JOIN Commissions on Commissions.Deal_ID=DealInfo.Deal_Number and Commissions.server_id=DealInfo.server_id 
WHERE DealInfo.server_id = '0000001412' and DealInfo.Status=2 and Coalesce(Commissions.GrossProfit,0)>0 and 
dealinfo.DeliveryDate BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
```

Comment: If this is a complete query (rather than just part of a query), then it's the wrong one, as it can't produce the error you've specified. For me – [and everyone else willing to take a look](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/17100) – it produces a syntax error. Which is fair, because you have a FROM clause following ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DealInfo.DeliveryDate, 
       Coalesce(SUM(Commissions.GrossProfit),0) as GP, 
       (SELECT CASE WHEN age < 16 THEN 'Under 16' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 16 and 20 THEN '16 - 20' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 21 and 25 THEN '21 - 25' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 26 and 30 THEN '26 - 30' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 31 and 35 THEN '31 - 35' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 36 and 40 THEN '36 - 40' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 41 and 45 THEN '41 - 45' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 46 and 50 THEN '46 - 50' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 51 and 55 THEN '51 - 55' 
                    WHEN age > 55 THEN 'Over 55' 
                    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'NULL' END as age_range, 
                    COUNT(*) AS RC 
        FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age 
              FROM   customers 
              WHERE  Customers.dob<>'0000-00-00' 
              and    Customers.server_id = '0000001412') as derived 
        GROUP BY age_range 
        ORDER BY age_range ASC) 
from   DealInfo 
LEFT JOIN Commissions 
on     Commissions.Deal_ID = DealInfo.Deal_Number 
and    Commissions.server_id = DealInfo.server_id 
WHERE  DealInfo.server_id = '0000001412' 
and    DealInfo.Status=2 
and Coalesce(Commissions.GrossProfit,0) > 0
```

Your scalar sub-query:

```
        (SELECT CASE WHEN age < 16 THEN 'Under 16' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 16 and 20 THEN '16 - 20' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 21 and 25 THEN '21 - 25' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 26 and 30 THEN '26 - 30' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 31 and 35 THEN '31 - 35' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 36 and 40 THEN '36 - 40' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 41 and 45 THEN '41 - 45' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 46 and 50 THEN '46 - 50' 
                    WHEN age BETWEEN 51 and 55 THEN '51 - 55' 
                    WHEN age > 55 THEN 'Over 55' 
                    WHEN age IS NULL THEN 'NULL' END as age_range, 
                    COUNT(*) AS RC 
        FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, CURDATE()) AS age 
              FROM   customers 
              WHERE  Customers.dob<>'0000-00-00' 
              and    Customers.server_id = '0000001412') as derived 
        GROUP BY age_range 
        ORDER BY age_range ASC)
```

returns 2 columns, it should return only one column.

Comment: It looks like you query is exacly the sam as mine and it returns the same error.

Comment: Obviously, you should modify your derived subquery.

Comment: I need help with how to write the query.  What would you suggest?

Comment: If it must return 2 values, you should move it to the JOIN section.